# Are these propositions equivalent?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

> Statement 1: Maria will find  job if she learns mathematics.
>   Statement 2: Maria will find a job unless she does not learn
>   mathematics.

I know the answer is probably that these are same, but it's bugging  me out. The second statements suggests that the only way for Maria to find a job is to learn mathematics. Explanations?

Comment: The first statement also indicated that a job will be found if she learns math. The condition is behind the "if"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement $2$ says that if Maria learns mathematics, she will find a job; in ordinary everyday English it also implies that if she does not learn mathematics, she will not find a job, but it doesn’t actually say so. What it actually says outright is *Maria will find a job unless she does not learn mathematics (and possibly even in that case)*. Thus, the two are equivalent.

In more formal terms, if $J$ is *Maria will find a job*, and $M$ is *Maria learns mathematics*, then Statement $1$ is clearly $M\to J$. Statement $2$ is a little trickier: it says that if Maria does not find a job, she must not have learned mathematics. In other words, it’s $\neg J\to\neg M$. This is the contrapositive of $M\to J$, and of course an implication and its contrapositive are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Maria will find a job **unless** she does **not** learn mathematics $\implies$

Maria will find a job **if it is not** the case that she does **not** learn mathematics $\implies$

(Double negation)

Maria will find a job if she learns mathematics.

Comment: I wonder if Maria ever got the job? +1 :-)